# How can I get a Java app to read "system" environment variables (from Info.plist) on Mac OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables

We have a Java app currently running on Windows that requires configuration information to work correctly on Windows XP vs Win 7.  That configuration information is defined using Windows system variables (applies to all users of the application), not user variables (applies only to the user currently running the application.)

My job is to make it work on the Mac (OS X 10.6.8) When I build the app for the Mac using JarBundler, I set the properties for these variables to the correct values, and I see them show up, as expected, in the Info.plist file in the app folder.  From my reading of available documentation, it appears that Info.plist properties should apply to all users of the app, similar to the Windows system environment variables.

However, when I create the package with PackageMaker, install it and then run the application,  null is returned as the value of these variables.  I am using the latest update of Java -- update 9.  (The return of null is seen as errors with null in the data field in the Console window... and the application hangs.)

I have verified that the Info.plist file is being installed; it is in the app folder, in the expected location, and that it contains the expected data.

If, rather than using info.plist, I create the file ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist with the same variables in it (using Property List Editor,) and reboot the computer, the application runs as expected, indicating valid data is being returned on request for the environment variables.

Because the goal is to make an end-user installable application through PackageMaker,  without requiring the user to create the hidden folder for environment.plist, move the file there manually, log out and in again, or reboot the computer, before being able to run the application,  I would prefer to find a solution using Info.plist.

Is there some trick to having the Java app correctly read the properties from Info.plist? Is there something that needs to be done either in JarBundler, PackageMaker, or through Property List Editor to make this work?

Or might this require some modification to the Java code?  (I do not know exactly what command is being used to read the environment variable data.  At present I do not have access to the source code, although I can get access to it, if needed to answer this question. )

Edit: Here's a fragment of my `Info.plist`:

```
<key>Properties</key> 
<dict> 
    ...
    <key>COMPENDIUM_DEVELOPER</key> 
    <string>true</string> 
    <key>CompendiumUserPath</key> 
    <string>/Applications/Compendium_CN</string> 
    <key>CompendiumSysPath</key> 
    <string>/Applications/Compendium_CN</string>
    ...
</dict>
```

Comment: @Mark Is there a way to attach a file here?  Apparently copy/paste of the text creates something too big to fit in the comment field!

This part should fit:

  <key>Properties</key>
  <dict>
   <key>COMPENDIUM_DEVELOPER</key>
   <string>true</string>
   <key>CompendiumUserPath</key>
   <string>/Applications/Compendium_CN</string>
   <key>CompendiumSysPath</key>
   <string>/Applications/Compendium_CN</string>
  </dict>

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `JavaApplicationStub`, you can specify the name of a shell script as the bundle's executable. Any environment variables defined there should be accessible to your program via `System.getenv()`. As an example, here's the `<dict>` entry from the NetBeans `Info.plist` that refers to the shell script `MacOS/netbeans`:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>netbeans</string>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll put that down as a possible approach.

Any ideas why Info.plist isn't working as expected from Java?

Comment: Shells inherit their environment variables; `JavaApplicationStub` has none, except what it gets from `environment.plist`.